# "Not available unless: You belong to <Some group>" : How to hide this message in moodle course

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I'm building a Moodle course for my students who are part of different batches. Each batch refers same lesson notes, but the Quiz and Assignment activities vary for each batch. The students are categorized into groups for the course and access to the activities is restricted. But the course page displays following message for restricted activities. :

"Not available unless: You belong to "

Is there any way to hide the activity as well as a message for restricted users.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the conditions by clicking on the 'eye' symbol beside the condition you want to hide:
https://docs.moodle.org/en/Restrict_access_settings#Hiding_the_conditions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden section and move the activity within, however the activity won't be accessible by the students in that case, expect if you're running Moodle 3.3. which is providing the new feature stealth mode: https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Stealth_activities

Maybe it's what you are looking for?